# Bootstrap 5 Offcanvas nav - combine 2 seperate navs

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, menu, navigation, bootstrap-5

I'm trying to combine a top navigation and main navigation into a single mobile navigation using Bootstrap's offcanvas component.

I can get this to work using a standard Bootstrap nav with data-target=".navbar-toggle", but i'm struggling using offcanvas.